# How to rewrite url in htaccess to hide subfolder?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

My website is located in a subfolder (gng2) of my public_html folder. The below code from the public_html/.htaccess file works fine in the sense that typing my domain loads the website properly from the subdirectory:

```
## redirect to subfolder containing the  app.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !gng2/
RewriteRule (.*) /gng2/$1 [L]
```

My problem is that [www.example.com/gng2/whateverpage](http://www.example.com/gng2/whateverpage) also works. I want to rewrite/reroute these urls to [www.example.com/whateverpage](http://www.example.com/whateverpage) so that the "gng2" subfolder does not show up for example in Google Analytics results.

How should I modify the above code to achieve this?

Thanks,
W.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this redirect rule in `gng2/.htaccess` to remove `/gng2/` from all URLs:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+gng2/(\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301,NE]

# other rules appear below this line
```

Comment: Do you mean that I should move my .htaccess file from public_html to the public_html/gng2 folder? Or shall I create a second .htaccess file in the gng2 subfolder with only these entries? Why I cannot put all entries in the public_html/.htaccess file? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I modified my public_html/.htaccess as below, but it does not rewrite the url even after clearing the caches. Any idea?                                                  
## redirect to subfolder containing the gng2 app.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+gng2/(\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301,NE]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !gng2/
RewriteRule (.*) /gng2/$1 [L]

Comment: Please see below an example of the url I want to rewrite: https://gonativeguide.com/gng2/en/tours/hungary/Budapest I used the tool: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ to test my htaccess content with this URL and it says that the condition you suggested was not met...

Comment: `madewithlove.be` is pretty useless for testing rewrite rules. It doesn't even support `THE_REQUEST`. Best place to test is on your local apache.

Comment: and I just checked that you using `server: nginx` not Apache. nginx doesn't support all mod_rewrite rules. Better you look into nginx documentation

Answer (score 0):

Please keep your htaccess file inside gng2 folder and try following rules in your htaccess rule file. Please make sure these rules are at top of your file(for applying http/HTTPS to URLs, in case you have more rules), also please do clear browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
## redirect to subfolder containing the  app.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
##Place your RewriteRule here.....
```

Comment: Can you please explain why I need to move my .htaccess file to the public_html/gng2 folder? Can I not simply add these entries to the top of the existing entries in the public_html/.htaccess file? Thanks!